# Why does the output become more predictable with a sleep fuction in multithreading in python3.7?

Tags: python, multithreading, gil

```
import threading
import time
NUM = 0
def addone():
    global NUM
    NUM += 1
    print(NUM)
    time.sleep(1) 

for i in range(10):
    t = threading.Thread(target = addone)
    t.start()

print('main thread stop')
```

(mac os X, 4 cores CPU, python 3.7.7 , vscode )

output( 9~10 out of 10 times ):

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
main thread stop
```

(wait 1 second here and then exit)

but if I annotate the `time.sleep(1)` in `function addone`,
the output will be more unpredcitable, like:

```
1
2
3
4
5
7
6
9
10
main thread stop
8
```

or so. Maybe 1 out of 10 times will get the same output of the previous case(with a sleep(1)).

I cannot figure it out why is that. I think maybe the GIL will take responsiblity.
Can anybody tell me what exactly happens down there?
(I know I should probably add a lock on that. I'm just really curious about this case without a lock.)

Comment: If you have several threads running in parallel, the order in which they execute statements is undefined and can be affected by seemingly unrelated changes. What behavior are you expecting? Should those numbers be printed sequentially or in parallel?

Comment: Indeed ```time.sleep``` releases GIL and allows other threads to run, but not sure if it has something to do with this.

Comment: @PiotrPraszmo Yes, I expect a sequential output without a lock. Each of those child-threads costs below 0.5 ms. So if there's a release of GIL,  the reason is not the timeout thing. The reason must be the I/O operations , I guess.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot guarantee that that threads will operate the order you like.
What you can do it to lock the increment operation + wait for all threads before final print.

In main (before function define)
pLock = threading.Lock()

in function:

global pLock
...
with pLock:
NUM += 1
print(NUM)

In main , define:
trds = []
in Thread loops add:
...
t.start()
trds.append(t)

and after start all threads:
for i in trds:
i.join()

Comment: OP want to know *why*, not how to implement lock.

Comment: The Lock use is exactly to avoid the situation.. this is explain why. Since the thread are working in parallel, each line in code is performs in different time , and delays - so that's what happening..

Comment: OP wants to know *why* when without lock output is in sequence when ```time.sleep``` is used.